# Google Play Pre-launch report not working properly due to resigning

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, firebase-test-lab, prelaunch

Is there a way to prevent Pre Launch on resigning the app similar to `--no-resign` of Firebase Test Lab [Beta](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/firebase/test/android/run#--resign) argument when using Google CLI? The reason for needing this is for the project to work properly specially when using some Google services such as Firebase which requires pre define signatures of SHA1 and SHA256 else the app won't run properly.